# How to change the styles (fonts, in particular) in a ArcToolbox tool UI?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arctoolbox, xsl

I am attempting to change the font size in my ArcToolbox tool UI. I have scoured the ArcGIS 10.0 online help and found nothing on this topic. Googling it turned up the [9.1 version](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/body.cfm?tocVisable=1&ID=-1&TopicName=More%20information%20on%20stylesheets), which has been helpful. I followed those instructions, and here is what I have done:

- I copied MdDlgContent.xsl that styles Tools to a local directory, the same as my Tool actually
- I edited the CSS and the HTML in MdDlgContent.xsl and have been successful in making a quite ugly Tool (just for the purpose of seeing whether I can make changes occur or not) where the background color, table border, table cell padding, and background image are changing:

[image]

Now, that said, I cannot, for the life of me, get the caption fonts (surrounded in red boxes above) to change. I have added/edited CSS and HTML all over the code, trying every dirty non-validating hack I know of. I would post the code, but it's just too much. The XSL, on my system, is located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Stylesheets

If you scroll down in the [9.1 help on this topic](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/body.cfm?tocVisable=1&ID=-1&TopicName=More%20information%20on%20stylesheets), they show an example where the font size and color have both been changed.

I'm thinking this is something that is right in front of me that I'm just not seeing and am wondering if anyone has figured this out before.

Comment: Did you find the example CSS file they used? http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/index.cfm?TopicName=Custom%20Stylesheet%20-%20SSContent.xsl

Comment: @blah238 - Yes, tried all that, including changing every `font` attribute imaginable in the CSS, both internally and inline.

Comment: I would like to see making font size changes to ArcMap windows and tool dialogs easy to do and well documented.  At the moment it seems to be neither.

Comment: For anyone wanting to vote on a related ArcGIS Idea to make changing font sizes in the ArcMap GUI easier I just submitted http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004EecIAE